# Starting Google Cloud TPU is missing VM image specification

Tags: tensorflow, google-compute-engine, gcloud, google-cloud-tpu

I deleted my old cloud TPU instance and wanted to make a new one with `ctpu up --preemptible`. But now it expects a specification for the accompanying VM's image, since I get this error message:

> Created TPU proj-name!
>   could not create Compute Engine instance without a base image

I don't think I had this problem when I set up my other instances. Anyhow I can't find any flag to set the image. I got the same result in the cloud shell and using another TPU region. This is my config:

```
Name:                 proj-name
  Zone:                 europe-west4-a
  GCP Project:          gcp-prj-name
  TensorFlow Version:   1.11
VM:
  Machine Type:     n1-standard-2
  Disk Size:        250 GB
  Preemptible:      false
Cloud TPU:
  Size:             v2-8
  Preemptible:      true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the config the tensorflow version is set to 1.11, which leads to this error since the TPU instance only works with tensorflow version 1.8 or 1.9. When I changed the config back to 1.9 it worked. How it changed to 1.11 I have no idea. My original answer stating this got deleted, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you run this command from? I did not see the error you are seeing when trying to reproduce the problem. Is this problem still persisting?